# Bunch of Could not find schema Information for element statements for xaml file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I'm writing an WPF application in Visual Studio 2010. My project compiles and runs correctly. But because of an unknown reason, from yesterday, the intellisense doesn't work for xaml files. And when a xaml file opens, a bunch of "could not find schema information for elements" statements appear in the error window. Could anyone tell me what causes this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to fix this issue. I had this issue also in the past and after googling I ended up that it is a nown issue in Visual Studio 2010. The problem I also noticed was that in my application (with multiple projects) Visual Studio did not build a part of my projects any more. Only deleting the ouput files helped.

Therefore I switched to Sharp Develop. Until now I dont have any strange issues with XAML or references any more. But maybe also a switch to VS2012 will help.